# Customization multiple tabs in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, gnome-terminal

Issue: Create a script that opens a terminal window with multiple tabs, each tab requires a different title to identify its purpose, in addition each tab should display a specific commmand (will not execute the command, the user will need to hit Enter to execute the command).

Example: The user needs to execute 3 commands: `ifconfig`, `route -n` and `top`, the user executes the script and it opens the terminal with 3 tabs, the first tab shows in the title `Network` and the prompt shows `root$ ifconfig`, the second tab shows in the title `Routing` and the prompt is like `root$ route -n`, the third tab shows the title `Performance` and the prompt shows `root$ top`. The commands are not running when the script is executed, the user needs to go into each tab and manually hit "Enter" to execute each command.

I am using the following script to open the terminal with multiple tabs, but am stuck trying to get the other features working, any assistance will be highly appreciated:

```
#bin/bash

tab="--tab"
cmd="bash -c 'pwd';bash"

foo=""

for i in 1 2 3; do

      foo+=($tab -e "$cmd")         
done

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

Comment: That should be `#!/bin/bash` (note the exclamation mark).

Comment: That should be `#!/bin/sh` and all bashisms for such an easy task better be avoided.

Comment: @Jens, please demonstrate how to perform this task safely and reliably in /bni/sh.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, you're right it was a typo error (the exclamation mark).

Comment: About the "bashisms", yea it's an easy task for 3 tabs, but in real life I need to open minimum 8 tabs and in each tab I need to type a different command with a large syntax, so I am looking for a way to automate the process. Any suggestion is welcome! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state of your terminal using:

```
gnome-terminal --save-config=FILE
```

And call the load with:

```
gnome-terminal --load-config=FILE
```

Where FILE is the filename you would like to save.

So you can open 3 tabs and give them names etc, then save the config and in your script you can load it.

On the saved file you can edit properties like:

```
WorkingDirectory=
Title=
```

As for displaying a command and not running it, I  don't have a solution.

You can check this:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-make-your-own-gnome-terminals/

Comment: Thanks gba! That sounds like it could help me with some of my tasks, I will give it a try today.